# I have a doubt regarding the reflection coefficient result for 'reflection and transmission of waves at a boundary'

Tags: waves, acoustics

So I found out that result for reflection coefficient is given different in different textbooks and websites. This really confused me as with one kind of result everything satisfies with free end & rigid reflection but for other it doesn't satisfy everything perfectly.

*RESULT 1:*
So I noticed that when they use equations of $\omega t - k x$ or $\cos \left( k x - \omega t \right)$ , they get reflection coefficient as $A_{r} = \frac{Z_{1} - Z_{2}}{Z_{1} + Z_{2}}$ in terms of impedance. Everything satisfies perfectly with this result for me.

*RESULT 2:*
But in some textbooks, when they use equations $k x - \omega t$ , they get reflection coefficient as $A_{r} = \frac{Z_{2} - Z_{1}}{Z_{1} + Z_{2}}$ in terms of impedance.

Now why do I have problem with the second result?
Let's take an example of $Z_{2} = 0$ and check with both results. This would be a case of free end reflection.

With *RESULT 1*, we get $A_{r} = A_{i}$, meaning if a crest is incident we get back a crest with same amplitude.

But with *RESULT 2*, we get $A_{r} = $-A_{i}$... This suggests an inversion but in reality there is no inversion.

Similarly problems occur for rigid end reflection.

[image: FREE END REFLECTION]
[image: FIXED END REFLECTION]

BOOK:PHYSICS OF WAVES AND VIBRATIONS
[image: PG1]
[image: PG2]
[image: PG3]

WEBSITE:
http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys283/lectures/transmit/transmit.html

[image: WEBSITE DERIVATION]

[VEDANTU WEBSITE DERIVATION](https://www.vedantu.com/iit-jee/reflection-and-transmission-of-waves)

Can anyone solve this for me??

Comment: Can you please provide to references that show different definitions? What textbooks are talking about ?

Comment: yes sure..i have edited the question with references added